# Problemas con Genymotion en XDE

Tags: react-native, debian, genymotion, expo

Al desplegar mis app  **React Native** en ***Genymotion*** desde XDE, me presenta el siguiente error:

> Couldn't start project on Android: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
>       ADB server didn't ACK
>       * failed to start daemon *   error: cannot connect to daemon

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi versión **adb** es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis configuraciones de variables **PATH** es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi versión de Linux:

- lsb_release -a
- No LSB modules are available.
- Distributor ID: Debian
- Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch)
- Release:        9.5
- Codename:       stretch

Espero puedan ayudarme.
¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Solución:
El problema lo solucioné ejecutando XDE desde la  terminal, así:
$ "/home/hmartinez/Descargas/xde-2.24.4-x86_64.AppImage" %U
Y luego abrir Genymotion
Nota: Cada vez que se use XDE hay que lanzarlo desde la terminal.
Saludos!